# Sending urban airship push notification to specific android device

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have device token "apid" from android phone. I get the valid response that notification is send. but i dont receive the notification. can some one please guide me i am using the following  code. i am using php for sending notification

$contents = array();

$contents['alert'] = 'test notification for android';

$notification = array();

$notification['android'] = $contents;

$platform = array();

array_push($platform, "android");

$dev['apid'] = 'valid_device_token_from_android' ;

$push = array("audience"=> $dev, "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);

$json = json_encode($push);

echo "Payload: " . $json . "\n"; //show the payload

$session = curl_init(PUSHURL);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));

$content = curl_exec($session);

echo "Response: " . $content . "\n";

Thanks

Comment: apid i provided was wrong. there are two type of keys in android. i used the other key and it worked